# How to revert date?

Tags: command-line, date, clock

I changed the system date using the following command in Ubuntu:

```
date -s="1999/01/01 12:34:56"
```

Now, I want to revert the `date` call so the date is correct again.  What should I do?

Comment: `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com `

Answer (score 4):

If you have `hwclock` and your hardware clock hasn't been set to the new value yet (could happen e.g. on a reboot or when switching to the standby mode):

```
hwclock --hctosys
```

(In some rare cases you might have to add `--utc`/`--localtime` to explicitly specify what your hardware clock runs on, in desktop systems the local time is commonly used for better compatibility with Windows in a dual-boot setup, otherwise it's normally UTC, AFAIK.)

Answer (score 3):

Building on @counglm's comment, if you have internet connectivity then use a public NTP or even if you have a local NTP , general command is:

```
ntpdate -u <ip-or-domain-name-of-ntp>
```

This assumes that you have ntpdate installed.

You can find public NTP [here](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/NTPPoolServers)

NTP stands for network time protocol used for syncing servers time with a reliable source. You can read up about it   [here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/warp.html)

More detailed time sync can be kept by installing ntpd (NTP daemon) and editing it's configuration file. Additionally you can also put ntpdate command in cron to run as you prefer and sync time.